# OneSignal Custom Prompt Settings & Notify Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, onesignal

How to customize the default OneSignal Prompt Settings & Notify Button?
[image]

I want to remove the notify button with a bell icon and change it with bootstrap alert that has a text message of "Do you want to subscribe to receive updates?" and just a two button with "Yes" or "No" options. When the user click "Yes" then subscribe the user. Basically I just want a subscribe button in the heading section of my page and not the button that OneSignal provide by dafault.

Comment: I want onesignal to automatically prompt the user to subscribe when they visit my website. How to do it?

Comment: @Ankit by `autoRegister: true,`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is OneSignal's guide on customizing or removing the notify button: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-prompts#section-subscription-bell

> **How do I hide the notify button after subscribing, or only show it on certain pages?**
>
> The notify button init options takes in a displayPredicate function which is evaluated before the notify button is shown. To hide the notify button, this function must return the value false or a Promise that resolves to the value false. You may return any other value to show the notify button.
>
> Here is an example hiding the notify button if the user is subscribed:
>
> JavaScript

```
// Do NOT call init() twice
// This is just an example
OneSignal.push(["init", {
    /* Your other init options here */
    notifyButton: {
        /* Your other notify button settings here ... */
        enable: true,
        displayPredicate: function() {
            return OneSignal.isPushNotificationsEnabled()
                .then(function(isPushEnabled) {
                    /* The user is subscribed, so we want to return "false" to hide the notify button */
                    return !isPushEnabled;
                });
        },
    }
}]);
```

---

And here's the guide on using your own Link/UI for the subscription prompt: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-sdk-setup-https#section-4-customizing-user-subscription

> **Subscribing Users With a Link**
>
> Here is an example. It adds a link that, when clicked, prompts the user to subscribe to notifications. This link is shown only if the user is unsubscribed, and notifications are supported.
>
> HTML

```
<body>
  <a href="#" id="subscribe-link" style="display: none;">Subscribe to Notifications</a>
  <script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async="async"></script>
  <script>
    function subscribe() {
      OneSignal.push(["registerForPushNotifications"]);
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    var OneSignal = OneSignal || [];
    /* This example assumes you've already initialized OneSignal */
    OneSignal.push(function() {
      // If we're on an unsupported browser, do nothing
      if (!OneSignal.isPushNotificationsSupported()) {
        return;
      }
      OneSignal.isPushNotificationsEnabled(function(isEnabled) {
        if (isEnabled) {
          // The user is subscribed to notifications
          // Don't show anything
        } else {
          document.getElementById("subscribe-link").addEventListener('click', subscribe);
          document.getElementById("subscribe-link").style.display = '';
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this. Just in case, seems `event.preventDefault();` won't execute in the code above.

Comment: @Gdeglin and all others, I want onesignal to automatically prompt the user to subscribe when they visit my website. How to do it?

Comment: how to automatically prompt the users to subscribe to notifications?

Comment: autoRegister: true

Comment: @ZameerFouzan, If you are using the WordPress plugin, just go to the plugin in your backend, and check the toggle that says "Attempt to automatically prompt new site visitors with Native Browser Prompt" this is not recommended by OneSignal themselves as it is seen as intrusive, but still your choice.